# Dato nuevo de Spinner en TableView NO guarda en mi data

Tags: javafx, spinner

Estoy imprimiendo un Spinner en mi tableView en JavaFx, junto con otros datos que vienen de mi data,  cuando presiono mi Spinner puedo capturar el nuevo valor e imprimirlo.
pero no he podido guardar ese nuevo valor en mi data. Para luego guardarla en mi bd. el nuevo valor de la TableView no setea el valor en mi tableView.
El valor de mi Spinner debe ser integer o IntegerProperty, por que así tengo mi variable que uso para otras cosas que ya funcionan.

```html
Columna3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Integer>("edad")); 

        Columna3.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Person, Integer>, TableCell<Person, Integer>>() {
            public TableCell<Person, Integer> call(TableColumn<Person, Integer> param) {
                TableCell<Person, Integer> cell = new TableCell<Person, Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                        if (item != null) {
                            // System.out.println(item);
                            valueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, item, 1);
                            valueFactory.setValue(item);
                            Spinner<Integer> spin = new Spinner<Integer>(1, 1, item);
                            spin.setEditable(true);
                            spin.setValueFactory(valueFactory);
                            spin.setPrefWidth(75.0);
                            spin.valueProperty().addListener(
                                    (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                                        System.out.println(obs.getValue());
                                    }
                            );
                            setGraphic(spin);
                        }
                    }

                };
                cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); 
                return cell;
            }
        });
```

cuando recorro mi TableView no veo mi nuevo valor seteado.
y lo necesito por que yo recorro mi tableView para guardar la info.

Mi clase Modelo es:

```html
public class Person {
    

  private final StringProperty firstName ;
  private final StringProperty lastName  ;
  private final IntegerProperty age;

                

  Person(String fName, String lName, Integer age) {
   this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
   this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
   this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
  }
                public Person() {
                    firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
                    lastName  = new SimpleStringProperty();
                    age = new  SimpleIntegerProperty();
                }

  public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
   return this.firstName;
  }

  public final java.lang.String getFirstName() {
   return this.firstNameProperty().get();
  }

  public final void setFirstName(final java.lang.String firstName) {
   this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
  }

  public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
   return this.lastName;
  }

  public final java.lang.String getLastName() {
   return this.lastNameProperty().get();
  }

  public final void setLastName(final java.lang.String lastName) {
   this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
  }

  public final IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
   return this.age;
  }

  public final int getAge() {
   return this.ageProperty().get();
  }

  public final void setAge(final int age) {
   this.ageProperty().set(age);
  }

 }
```

Una de las soluciones que busco, seria al momento de darle click a mi spinner que este seleccione automaticamente la celda donde esta mi spinner, y poder sacar la posicion de la celda en la tabla y asi de manera manual yo guardar el nuevo valor en mi data. Pero en esa solución no he podido capturar la posición de la celda en la que esta el spinner